# Get Traffic Jam Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, traffic

Is it possible to get a response (true or false) if are a traffic jam from your position to your destination, using google maps android API? Or using google maps web api?

Can not find anythink about that.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is no direct Google endpoint that can answer this question. However, you can implement a workaround using a [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) web service or [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) web service. If you specify a departure time in the request, the response will contain fields `duration` and `duration_in_traffic`. So you can figure out if `duration_in_traffic` is much bigger than `duration` and decide if there is a traffic jam somewhere on this route.

For example,

I execute Distance Matrix API request for two points in Barcelona

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=av%20Diagonal%20198%2C%20Barcelona&destinations=plaza%20Espa%C3%B1a%2C%20Barcelona&departure_time=now&key=MY_API_KEY`

The response is

```
{
  "destination_addresses":[
    "Av. del Paraŀlel, s/n, 08015 Barcelona, Spain"
  ],
  "origin_addresses":[
    "Avinguda Diagonal, 198, 08018 Barcelona, Spain"
  ],
  "rows":[
    {
      "elements":[
        {
          "distance":{
            "text":"6.0 km",
            "value":6049
          },
          "duration":{
            "text":"17 mins",
            "value":1035
          },
          "duration_in_traffic":{
            "text":"19 mins",
            "value":1134
          },
          "status":"OK"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status":"OK"
}
```

Comparing `duration_in_traffic` and `duration` from my response I can say that currently there are no traffic jams on this route.

I hope this helps!